python ffmpeg configuration for command
I want to convert mp3 files to mp3 but with my settings. Could someone help me to create python code or a command for cmd to perform such action with ffmpeg? I have hundreds of mp3 files so I need to automate it. Settings are in below picture.

I tried myself to configure it, but I had problems with finding in ffmpeg docs information about bit rate mode and quality settings.

import subprocess

def convert_mp3(input_filepath:str, output_filepath:str):
  #FFmpeg command to convert the input MP3 file
  ffmpeg_cmd = [
    'ffmpeg',
    '-i', input_filepath,
    '-ar', '48000',  # Set the sample rate to 48000Hz
    '-b:a', '320k',  # Set the audio bitrate to 320kbps
    '-vn',  # Disable video stream
    '-codec:a', 'libmp3lame',  # Use LAME MP3 codec
    '-f', 'mp3',  # Specify the output file format as MP3
    output_filepath
  ]
  subprocess.run(ffmpeg_cmd, check=True)

Insure that 'ffmpeg' is a recognized command by adding the path of your ffmpeg/bin folder to your environment variables.
